# How to Allocate Memory for a Bunch of Objects at One Shot?

Tags: c++, memory, heap-memory, shared-ptr, new-operator

I am trying to parse an input file in C++. In the beginning of the file, the number of lines to be read is given. After reading each line, I have to create an object containing the data in the line. I keep a pointer to each object in a vector like `vector<shared_ptr<MyClass>>`.

What I want to do is to allocate enough space for all the objects as soon as I know the number of lines. However, I guess that if I use the `reserve()` function for my vector, enough space will be allocated to hold the pointers not the objects.

1. What should I do to allocate space both for the objects and the pointers?
2. How would this change if I want to use `make_shared()` when creating my objects? In other words, how should I allocate enough space for the pointers and the pointers manager?

Comment: If you do this you will have a devil of a time with `shared_ptr`. Why do you want `shared_ptr` anyway? Assignment requirement?

Comment: Do you need a vector of pointers? Would allocating a buffer to hold all the objects be feasible?

Comment: Why would you not use `std::string` to hold the file data?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Doesn't `resize()` allocate space for the `shared_ptr`s?

@user4581301: I have a couple of classes that need to keep pointers to objects of a third class and they should both be able to modify the objects of the third class.

Comment: @JamesRoot: I want to allocate enough space for the pointers and the objects the pointers are pointing at. And I need the objects to be created on the heap, so that they can be accessed later.

Comment: @Xirema: Parsing the input is just the initial phase of my program. I have to perform other operations on the objects later on.

Comment: @Mahdi Sure, it only allocates space for the `shared_ptr`'s. Better than `reserve()` though.

Comment: That's not quite what `shared_ptr` is for. Shared pointer is to allow multiple objects to share ownership of another object. It's a sort of contract that the shared object will not be deleted until everyone with skin in the game is done using the object.This case can be managed with a `unique_ptr` to a single large buffer of appropriate size places at a wide enough scope that it won't be destroyed prematurely or a `shared_ptr` to the same pool owned by all the owning classes. The vector can then contain raw pointers to the data inside the buffer and no one will care.

Comment: Isn't a `vector<MyClass>` exactly what you're asking for?

Comment: Also note that creating a pool of strings just gets empty strings. The strings may still have to allocate the storage they need to actually hold anything.

Comment: @immibis In this case very likely. Mahdi knows the size and presumably isn't going to resize after the fact.

Comment: @immibis: I have a couple of classes that need to keep pointers to objects of a third class and they should both be able to modify the objects of the third class. I assume if I use your strategy, different objects of the third class will be created.

Comment: @Mahdi, the other users can  be given pointers to the elements of the vector so long as you do nothing to trigger a reallocation of the vector's data store.

Comment: @user4581301: I would like to avoid raw pointers as much as I could. It looks like this is a better approach starting C++11 (not sure about this).

Comment: The avoidance of raw pointer comes from a tendency toward fuzzy ownership. In this case the ownership is nailed down to the vector, so the worries of who manages and `delete`s the pointer when it's no longer needed is known. The real problem is in the vector going out of scope too soon, easily solved, and the vector being resized and the pointers being rendered invalid.

Answer (score 6):

It seems that [Pool Allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_pool) would work for you. It preallocates large chunks of memory and places objects created later in it. There is an [`std::allocate_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/allocate_shared) function which allows you to control where control block for `std::shared_ptr` and object would be created. You can also overload [member operator `new`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) for your class to force it to use your allocator when you insert it in vector too, or just use pool allocator to create objects in first place.

[Boost.Pool](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/pool/doc/index.html) is a ready to use implementaion of pool allocator.